Meaning of "quasi-isomorphism" of diagram indexed by the negative integers
I've been given this exercise:

Fix a commutative unital ring $R$ and a diagram $$A^\bullet = \cdots \to A_{-2} \to A_{-1}\to A_{0}$$ of
objects and maps in $\mathrm{Ch}(R \mathrm{-Mod})$ indexed by the category $\mathbb Z_{≤0}$. Prove that there is a
canonical quasi-isomorphism of diagrams $A^\bullet \to  I^\bullet$
such that each $I^n$
is a DG-injective chain complex
and each map $I^n \to I^{n+1}$ is an epimorphism.

My problem is: what is a quasi-isomorphism of diagram in this context? I initially thought to just add a sequence of zeros after $A^0$ and consider the diagram as indexed by $\mathbb Z$, but it is not enough to make sense: we would need also that any composition of two chain complex maps $A^n\to A^{n+1}\to A^{n+2}$ is equal to zero, in order to speak of homology and quasi-isomorphism. Maybe you see what the exercise mean? Thanks

Each object in the diagram is a chain complex. A componentwise quasi-isomorphism of diagrams is meant.

@ZhenLin I'm sorry to disturb you, since you seem well informed on the subject may I ask if you know some material that I should read in order to do the exercise? My knowledge of homological algebra consists basically of chapters 1,2,5 of Weibel, and what I know about DG-injective complexes comes exclusively from the paper that you linked to me in the previous question. There is indeed a useful fact there, i.e. that any complex has a DG-injective resolution, but I'd like to see a proof or some context about it, because without it I don't see how the resolutions $I^n$ assemble in a diagram.

If you have a morphism of diagrams of chain complexes (of some fixed shape), then in particular you have morphisms between the chain complexes at each corresponding point of the diagrams.
A quasi-isomorphism of diagrams of chain complexes is simply one where each of those morphisms is a quasi-isomorphism.
As for the exercise: just build up the required diagram inductively.
(I find the use of "canonical" there bizarre considering that injective resolutions are far from canonical.)
The key fact is that for any morphism of chain complexes $g : B \to C$, there is a factorisation $B \to \hat{B} \to C$ where $B \to \hat{B}$ is a monic quasi-isomorphism and $\hat{B} \to C$ is a degreewise split epimorphism with dg-injective kernel.
This is the (trivial cofibration, fibration) factorisation in the injective model structure on chain complexes: see [Hovey, Model category structures on chain complexes of sheaves].
